# Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

Tags: hibernate

I'm getting this error:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
```

Is this error is cause by Jar Imports or the database (MySQL table) problem can cause the problem?

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add SLF4J to classpath, recent versions of Hibernate use it for logging. You can [get it from here](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html).

Comment: I wonder why doesn't hibernate dependency bring in slf4j along with it?

Answer (score 1):

You basically need these 2 dependencies (its better if they have the same version) :

`slf4j-api-1.*.*.jar`

`slf4j-simple-1.*.*.jar`

Look at your maven dependencies by using the command  `mvn dependency:tree`

See if these dependencies are being loaded. If only one of them is being loaded add the other dependency with the same version.
In my case i added this

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8</version>
</dependency>`

I referred from  [this](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html)